# How can I implement fields translation in prestashop module's configuration page?

Tags: localization, module, translation, prestashop

I made a custom module to upload images with links. All fine till now. Now, I've got to add the ability to translate the fields. I mean, different images/links for different active languages.

How can I do it o what's the correct way? I cannot find specific documentation. They speak a lot about label translations but nothing about content/field translations.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All field should be named like that: image_1, url_1 - image_2, url_2 where this "2" is the language id.

Look at the modules/homeslider/homeslider.php this should be helpfull for you.